# Scipy installation fails because of numpy

Tags: numpy, scipy

I am trying to deploy a python application on the cloud. The dependencies are stored in requirements.txt. The installation of scipy fails due to its own dependency on numpy. Since the requirements are not installed serially, scipy can not get installed.

I cannot use conda or pip directly because of organization's policies.

I have to vendor the requirements for the same reason.

Comment: If you're not using pip or conda, it's not clear how you are using your list of requirements; supplying your deployment script could help to clarify.

Comment: @fuglede I cannot simply simply use pip/conda install <package>. As I said, I have to vendor the dependencies as mentioned here : https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/tree/master/fixtures/flask